# Adding buttons and scrollable panel to a tab - Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to build a Java GUI where among other things there will be several tabs. 
In one of the tabs I want to have both a scrollable JTextArea, and also some buttons at the top/bottom that interacts with the JTextArea. I can't figure out how to get both into the same tab, I'm either getting the buttons and a non-scrollable jtextarea, or just the scrollable jtextarea. I also don't want to display the button in the other tabs. Here is my code:

```
private final JTextArea music = new JTextArea();
private final JTextArea button = new JTextArea();
private final JTextArea test = new JTextArea();
private final JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
private JTable table;

music.append(newPlaylist.toString());
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
frame.setTitle("Music File Organiser");

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
JButton button1 = new JButton("Hello");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Sort by Album Title");
JButton button3 = new JButton("Sort by Track Title");

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {code};
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {code};
button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {code};

panel.add(music);
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);
panel.add(button3);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(table);

tab.add("Music Files", scroll);
tab.add("Table", scroll2);

this.add(tab);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setSize(1200, 1000);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The tab in mind is the first one. How do I add buttons to "scroll"? The way I'm trying it here is to add the JTextArea "music" into panel, then adding the buttons to the same panel, then adding the panel to a JScrollPane, and then adding the JScrollPane to tab. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate your visual elements into child Panels.

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); //panel for buttons.
buttonPanel.add(button1);
buttonPanel.add(button2);
buttonPanel.add(button3);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(music); //scrollable pane for JTextArea

panel.add(buttonPanel);
panel.add(scroll); //add sub-components to panel for tab

/*here you would add some layout code to fit the panel and scroll into the associated spaces */

tab.add("Music Files", panel); //add panel to tab
```

Comment: Child panels sounds very smart. But how can I "add some layout code" to panel? I mean, it's the same panel, so how can I tell the buttonPanel to stay at the top and scroll to stay at the bottom?

Comment: [How to use a LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) You can also use a GUI design tool like [WindowBuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to see your designs without having to recompile.

Comment: Very aware of this but WindowBuilder is too easy :)
Got a step further now, get both scrolling and buttons, but the buttonpane disappears as soon as I start scrolling..

Comment: @user3001634 Make sure the buttons are not part of the scrollpane. I don't see why it would vanish otherwise. If it continues, a new question might be applicable as the original problem is technically solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    JPanel tab = new JPanel()
    JPanel tabWithButtons = new JPanel()
    JPanel tabWithScrollPanel = new JPanel()

    tab.add(tabWithScrollPanel)
    tab.add(tabWithButtons)
```

IMO this is better way, because I assume that buttons shouldn't be included in JScrollPane and they should be visible all the time

Of course, you have to add all elements to proper JPanels.

Also, you can try with width/height settings of panel which contains all your elements, maybe ScrollArea panel is to big?